# How to line up text beside a table's row separators?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to write text that lines up like this:

[image]

Comment: Is the downward pointing arrow pointing to the bottom-left of the same cell the upward pointing one is or to the top-left of the next cell?

Comment: Exactly! I want the text to be centered so there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table/cell alignment in the design tab.  If it still does not align perfectly then highlight the text and then use the ruler to do fine adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, here is what I would do by inserting text boxes. Just format the box and text, then align the box where you want it.

[image]